# onCreateOptionsMenu is not called after a fragment add & remove

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-menu

I have a fragment where I can call `ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());` and the method `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is successfully called on both: Activity and Fragment.

However, when I add a fragment on top of the fragment with:

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_home, fragment2, "fragment_ID");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

and later close it (either by backPress or by `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`), `ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());` becomes unresponsive. `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is not called at all.

I know for sure, that it will work if I use `replace()` instead of `add()`, however, for some reasons, I need to use `add()`.

on Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_home);
    if (fragment != null)
        fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, getMenuInflater());
    return true;
}
```

on Fragment 1:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu() called with: ...");
    // additional code
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: Have you attached more than one fragment using add() method?

Comment: not via `add()` method. Activity => replaceFragment => replaceFragment => replaceFragment => addFragment => back ===> unresponsive `invalideOptionsMenu`

Comment: You only need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView()` . And try to manipulate menu in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. If issue exists add your Activity's theme in question.

Comment: They were initially on `onCreateView()`, just changed to see if there is any effect. `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called on both - Activity and Fragment, but not `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_home);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, getMenuInflater());
        return true;
    }
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I did and it didn't help. I am also not sure how it suppose to help, as `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) ` is also not called after I close the fragment and call `ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());`

Comment: Inside the Activity have you override onPrepareOptionMenu() method?

Comment: Yes and no, as it returns the default:

`@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HomeOnPrepareOptionsMenu");
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }`

Comment: In menu_layout you need to use your menu layout

Comment: It is not helping... I don't have a menu for the Activity. The point of the above code is to let the activity know that we are using menu from the fragment, not from the Activity.

Comment: Have you debug this code ?
are you getting fragment is coming properly, not null.