# onOptionsItemSelected is not called after remove+replace fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632835/oncreateoptionsmenu-is-not-called-after-a-fragment-add-remove). But there is no any solution yet!

Back button doesn't work for some cases.

```
MainActivity -> replace A -> add B -> remove B
```

Back button of fragmentA works! But below step doesn't work:

```
MainActivity -> replace A -> add B -> remove B + replace C -> replace A + add B -> remove B
```

Back button of A doesn't work. Also, after removing fragment B, onCreateOptionsMenu is called for fragment A.

[This guide](http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2015/08/16/how-to-avoid-fragments-overlapping-due-to-backstack-nightmare-in-android/) uses remove+remove together. I expect that remove+replace or replace+add work.

Each fragment use below code in OnCreateView callback:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
activity.setSupportActionBar(this.toolbar);
```

Activity onOptionItemSelected callback:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem menuItem) {
        if(menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Selected home btn");
            // some code
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you handle fragment's menu items in fragment's `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: No, I don't handle in fragments

Comment: Also, home button is visible :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can help, but try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem menuItem) {
    if(menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Selected home btn");
        // some code
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); //call super if menu item wasn't consumed
}
```

Comment: I change the steps. MainActivity -> replace A -> add B -> remove B + replace C -> add B -> replace A + remove B. This is works! I think adding two visible fragment add/replace to activity causes this error!

Comment: @us2956 also don't you mind trying to move `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` into fragment's constructor?

Comment: MainActivity -> replace A -> add B -> remove B + replace C -> add B -> replace A + remove B. No need move `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` into fragment's constructor for this case.